# How to control the SSL ciphers available to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, encryption

I'm unable to disable weak SSL ciphers in Tomcat as documented in many places e.g. http://www.techstacks.com/howto/secure-ssl-in-tomcat.html.
Currently, my connector looks as follows:

```
..Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\keystore" keystorePass="nn"/>
```

when I attempt a connection (using IE or ssldigger) I get the following error in Tomcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.createSSLEngine(NioEndpoint.java:1141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:1096)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Incidentally, I removed the unsupported ciphers (almost one by one) and the only one I was left with that seems to be supported is SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Also, I'm assuming that an unsupported cipher is not related to Tomcats's specific key pair but more generally to the broadly available ciphers.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out..the comma separated list of ciphers is whitespace sensitive i.e. the culprit is the space character after the comma

Comment: You may accept this answer as well if it has worked, quite important bit of info here.

Comment: Wow, yeah.  This just saved my butt.  I have been looking at this problem for close to 12 hours and found this answer.  This should be shouted from the rooftops.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt for you to have told the Tomcat version, as it depends on which tags can be used in the Connection block. I have this similar issue with a web service running on Tomcat 6.0, and have read that for e.g.

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,..."
```

Might not work correctly, as the "ciphers" might need to be as **SSLCipherSuite**, but I am not 100% sure on this. Document which led me to think this might be applicable is found here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html . In that same page, it is also said that the delimiter is not a comma (,) but a colon (:).
So for Tomcat 6.0 I would suggest using either:

```
SSLCipherSuite="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:..."
```

or

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:..."
```

Hope this helps someone who has to struggle with Tomcat 6.0 (disregard this answer for Tomcat 6.0.XX or higher.)

Comment: If the cipher suite is specified in openssl notation then colon(:) is to be used as separator. APR connector uses OpenSSL. otherwise its comma(,)