# unsupported SSL ciphersuite

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I am trying to use some custom SSL cipher suites. Specifically my list is

```
<util:list id="ciphers" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA</value>
    <value>AES256-SHA</value>
    <value>CAMELLIA256-SHA</value>
    <value>SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5</value>    <---this is the only one working
    <value>PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA</value>
    <value>EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA</value>
    <value>EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA</value>
    <value>DES-CBC3-SHA</value>
    <value>PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA</value>
    <value>DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA</value>
    <value>AES128-SHA</value>
    <value>CAMELLIA128-SHA</value>
    <value>PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA</value>
</util:list>
```

,initialized by Spring and passed to method

```
tlsClientParameters.setCipherSuites()
```

Unfortunately my client fails to connect to a stub server that I have created. The exception I am getting is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(CipherSuite.java:171)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:62)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:1977)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLSocketFactoryWrapper.enableCipherSuites(SSLSocketFactoryWrapper.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLSocketFactoryWrapper.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryWrapper.java:71)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:372)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:883)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1394)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1336)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1414)
... 41 more
```

When I tried removing the ciphers suites one by one, the same exception kept appearing with a different cipher every time, until there was only SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 left. This is the only one that seems to be working.

I had a look at [How to control the SSL ciphers available to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417809/how-to-control-the-ssl-ciphers-available-to-tomcat) that seems an identical issue, but I don't have an whitespaces.

Edit: as a sidenote, my system is running on Java 1.5 could it be that these ciphers are just not supported at this java version? If not, is there a way around this ?

Update: We migrated to Java 7 and I am still getting the same issue. I think that it's related to one of the answers below saying that these are not the standard names for the ciphers, and are thus not recognized by java. If that is the case, how can I find the standard names for these ciphers ?

Comment: The ciphernames you use seem to be non-standard (except for the one that works), the standard ciphers (from [RF5246](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-A.5) and the [IANA TLS Cipher Suite Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-3)) all start with `TLS_` (or `SSL_` for SSL)

Comment: Given that you care about this enough to specify custom cipher suites, then for the love of Pete, remove RSA. Most sensible people believe that it has only a few months of life left (even if it hasn't already been broken in secret).

Comment: so according to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html 80% of the ciphers in the supported under Java 7 are broken ? Sorry, I am no expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the list of ciphers I was using was from [openssl](http://openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) and they were generated by

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW:-KRB5'.
```

I never found how to translate the openssl list of ciphers to the java 7 supported ones (or confirm whether they are the same ciphers, just under different names). I just changed my ciphers list to be the list provided here by Java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

and everything worked okay.

Comment: Late but: the mapping between standard and OpenSSL names was on [the webpage you linked](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html)
now [moved by reorg](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html) about halfway down under "CIPHER SUITE NAMES".
To go from standard to OpenSSL: drop leading `SSL_` or `TLS_`, drop `RSA_` for plain-RSA KX, swap `(EC)DH_anon` to `A(EC)DH`,
drop `WITH_`, usually swap `3DES_EDE_CBC` to `DES-CBC3` and usually drop other `_CBC`, drop a few other uneeded bits and some `_` and change remaining `_` to `-`.

Answer (score 5):

> Could it be that these ciphers are just not supported at this java version?

Certainly. The available cipher suites are documented. See the [Standard Names document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html).

> If not, is there a way around this?

Not unless you can find another implementation that supports them.

Comment: Interestingly, we just upgraded to java 7 and i am still getting the same exception under java 7.

Comment: Where did you get these cipher suite names? And what's the basis of your expectation that *any* implementation will support them?

Comment: openssl  http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html generated by openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW:-KRB5'. I understand that they may not be supported, but aren't (similar?) versions of them supported by java under other names ?

Comment: Try them with underscores instead of hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

[Sun Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html).

Also,

By default the **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar** under ***`jre_home`/lib/security/*** might not "*enable*" the cipher suites you want.

To enable them, replace those two files with the ones found here [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

You should not be able to use the cipher suites supported under Sun Providers.

Make sure that the cipher suite descriptions match the ones under the Sun Providers.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get the SSLServerSocket
SSLServerSocketFactory ssl;
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket;
ssl = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssl.createServerSocket();

// Get the list of all supported cipher suites.
String[] cipherSuites = sslServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
for (String suite : cipherSuites)
  System.out.println(suite);

// Get the list of all supported protocols.
String[] protocols = sslServerSocket.getSupportedProtocols();
for (String protocol : protocols)
  System.out.println(protocol);
```